# Merge two image in windows universal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have 1.png (150x150 size) and 2.png (150x150 size). I use this code for make a stackpanel (310x150 size):

```
StackPanel mygrid = new StackPanel();
        mygrid.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        Image myimage1 = new Image();
        myimage1.Width = 150; myimage1.Height = 150;
        myimage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///assets/1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        Image myimage2 = new Image();
        myimage2.Width = 150; myimage2.Height = 150;
        myimage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///assets/2.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        mygrid.Children.Add(myimage1);
        mygrid.Children.Add(myimage2);
```

Then I convert this stackpanel to Image:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(mygrid, 310, 150);
```

I want to save this image in "ms-appx:///assets/3.png" (like this name) and use that. In this way, I merge two image to one image But I can't save them to 3.png. How can I do that?
If this is not a good way to merge two picture in one picture, Is it possible to help me?

Update:  I'm sorry but question has problems and it is deleted. I can't delete it because there is answer on it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I update my post.  Is it possible to help me? It's very important for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using generally the wrong approach to do this. I would load the 2 images into `WriteableBitmap`s and then blend them with the [WriteableBitmapEx library](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)

Having said that, here is how you can save the `WriteableBitmap` as png, taken from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-save-WriteableBitmap-bd23d455):

```
    // Save the writeableBitmap object to JPG Image file 
    IStorageFile saveFile = todo;// insert your code for opening the file here

    IRandomAccessStream stream = await savefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    // Get pixels of the WriteableBitmap object 
    Stream pixelStream = renderTargetBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
    await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    // Save the image file with jpg extension 
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
```

You try to save the image as `ms-appx:///assets/3.png` that won't work as you can't save the image in the application package.

You need to save it to somewhere where your app has write access to.

Comment: Thanks for help. I update my post. can you see that and help me again?

Comment: my answer already answers your question. Once again: You can't save the file into your application package

Comment: I understand that I can't save it in my application project But how can I use that In my Tile. I wrote the tile code. can you help me?

Comment: if you have another question then you should post another question